# iphone session management

Tags: iphone, session

How can I manage user sessions in an iPhone app? I get a username and password from the user on the first page of my app. The user may log out whenever he wants. How can I store session information in an iPhone app like any other web application? Is there any other technique for that?
thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? Do you mean a web service session your app connects to? Do you mean "quit" by logging out? Have you looked into NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Are you developing an html only app?

Comment: i've been devloping iphone app, not iphone web app. when user logs in my app (submitting his username and password) i store their credentials by using NSUSerDefaults. But, user may log off whenever he tapped the logout button. So, what should i do when he tapped the logout button. And how should i check user session info in every page of the app. am i sufficiently clear? Briefly, how can i handle user session control mechanism (like in a standart web project) in the iphone app (i'm developing iphone window-based app, not iphone web proect).
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `NSUserDefaults` from anywhere in your app. This is usually where state information is stored.

If you envision that you might have to store information for a large number of users, you should create a custom database and only rely on . The easiest way to do that is to use [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH1-SW1). You can park the managed object context in the application delegate and then access that from anywhere by calling the app delegate.

I would caution you that an iPhone app has a different design pattern than a web app. You shouldn't be thinking in terms of pages and sessions unless you are implementing a web based interface.

Comment: hello, what about Keychain to store username/passwprd? I mean, I have 4 view controller and I want to use session in all controller. How can i do that? NSUserDefaults OR Keychain?

Answer (score 0):

you can **save username information on [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**

```
-(void)saveToUserDefaults:(NSString*)myString
 {
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"username"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }
 }
```

if you have username information on NSUserDefaults, you can **get your username information**

```
-(NSString*)retrieveFromUserDefaults
 {
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *val = nil;

    if (standardUserDefaults) 
        val = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"username"];

    return val;
 }
```

**using**:

```
NSString * username=[self retrieveFromUserDefaults:@"username"];
if (!([username length]==0)||![username isEqualToString:@""]) 
{
NSLog(@"no authentication and redirect authentication page ");
}
else 
{
NSLog(@"it's authentication!");
}
```