# Iphone session management

Tags: ios, session, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070754/iphone-session-management)

Hello,

I have web site with login. I make iPhone app for my site. How should I mange my sessions. When server send me id. How to manage it and how to make customer to log in automaticaly next time?

Thanks