# How to create and manage session in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, session

I have an application which uses wcf web service and after successful login, i want to activate a session of 10 minutes. If user is idle or app is in background for 10 minutes then session should expire and app should ask for login details again.

I have used keychain for storing username and password and it works But i want to add the session so that user is redirected to main page if session is not expired and to the login page if session is expired...

I know this is repeated question but i had to write it since i am not getting proper answer from other questions. Please help..

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070754/iphone-session-management/16934038#16934038

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use this [Link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/) this works me.

use **NSUserDefault** to create Session for ios.

i also created Session in ios with this Tutorial.

**EDIT:**

i have a Login Screen in first Page of My application

if Login is Successfull authenticate by server then i stored my Username & Password in **NSUserDefault** Like this way:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [defaults setObject:userNameText forKey:@"username"];               
     [defaults setObject:passWordText forKey:@"password"];
     [defaults synchronize];
```

**Onclick** of Login Button. & redirected to Dashboard.

In dashboard Logout Button is there if user click **Logout** Delete All Data Like this way.

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"username"];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"password"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

& On other condition when user close app The **NSUSerDefault** Are stored when u second time open app at that time Check wheather **username** & **password** stored in **NSUserDefault**
During `ViewDidAppear` of **Loginpage**.

```
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // check if user is alraidy Login
    if([defaults objectForKey:@"username"]!=nil  && ![[defaults objectForKey:@"username"] isEqualToString:@""]){
        // Redirected to Dashboard.
}
```

If sucessfull then  Redirected to Dashboard.

Comment: Can you specify how did you created session using NSUserDefault?

Comment: Well, this is just for the autologin and doesnot start or expire the session if the user stays idle for very long time..

Comment: you should try your self use of NStimer its just hint

Comment: for more information Refer this Example https://github.com/tejaswiyvs/AutoLogoutForiOS

Comment: i guess i will start a timer when app goes to background and when it enters foreground i would recheck timer and go to login/dashboard appropriately..

Comment: I know this answer is old but this is the absolute WORST way to handle sessions for iOS. It was a bad answer back in '13 and it still is now. `NSUserDefaults` stores info in cleartext, a terrible security idea.

Comment: What if you change password at server side through other device ?

Comment: How to clear app data on click of Logout Button. ? I having 100+ viewController.swift file??

Comment: You should never store raw password of user either on device or cloud, store its hash instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AFNetworking framework](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), it auto store your session, I had tested my APIs and it worked

Comment: How AFNetworking comes into picture? It is used to check network connections.