# User authentication and Session handling in iOS with swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, session, authentication

I am fairly new to Swift and I am required to develop an app which `authenticates` username and password through a `REST API` in `Azure`. I have successfully called the API and received the `JSON` string for a valid user.
Now I want to make the user login to the app with his credentials after authentication, a session should be created so that user data persists after login and till he doesn't log out.

I am confused on how to create the session of the user. Can I get any resource where I can find how it is done?

PS: I don't want to use `Parse` or any other framework. I already have created custom API in azure which I call for retrieving data as `JSON String.`

Comment: wouldn't a keychain manager handle what you need?

Comment: Though i have less idea about keychain manager, I just want to authenticate the user, and create the session, I have not thought of security factors as of now, but yes once I am able to let the user login, I would surely like to work about the security issues.

Comment: i mean you could use the keychain manager as the session handler. this way its also secured. you could read on that. the worst thing you can do is use an NSUserDefault to handle your credentials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iphone session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070754/iphone-session-management)